# Is there any way to make custom Spannables on Android?

Tags: android, linkify, spannablestring, spannable

In my Android app I've got text views with links. Each of them is toggling a particular event (opening browser, starting another activity, etc...). To handle that, I haven't found any better solution than doing this:

```
hi there!, this is <u>a action</u> and this is <b>another action</b>. This third one goes to <a href="http://google.com>Google</a>
```

Then, when displaying the textview, I convert each link to a custom spannable with a SpannableStringBuilder.

I know this is hacky. And this is why I want to know if there's any other better way?

I've got two ideas:

- Is it possible to implement custom spannables with their own marshalling system? For example a custom spannable matching tags like:

  `<div class="foo"></div>`

Then I'd have a `FooClickableSpannable` extending `ClickableSpan` automatically detected with `fromHtml()`

- I could use custom url schemes to open my activities but I'm not sure how to force it not to display an app chooser if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement custom spannables with their own marshalling system?

Can you create custom subclasses of `CharacterStyle`, particularly `ClickableSpan`? Yes.

I have no idea what "their own marshalling system" means, though.

> I could use custom url schemes to open my activities but I'm not sure how to force it not to display an app chooser if there are other alternatives.

Well, a true custom scheme (e.g., `piel://` instead of `http://` or `content://`) is unlikely to present a chooser, since it is unlikely that there will be another alternative.

Beyond that, what I have done in the past is:

- Use `Html.fromHtml()` for a basic conversion
- Use `getSpans()` on the results to find all the `URLSpan` objects
- replaced those `URLSpan` objects with other sorts of custom spans where needed via `removeSpan()` and `setSpan()`

Another approach would be to create a workalike for `Html.fromHtml()`. This is something that's rattling around the lower levels of my own TODO list, to create something that is more extensible, handles more HTML constructs, etc.

Comment: thanks for this comment, I think your last paragraph is what i want to do in my first suggestion (see my updated question). This is actually very interesting, the data-scheme solution is a quick fix but might not be the cleanest solution. I'll try to see how i can do my Html.fromHtml() workalike.

Comment: @RomainPiel: Another possibility is to invent totally new tags, if this content will not be viewed outside of your app. So a `<piel>...</piel>` tag would ordinarily be ignored, but you could attach an `Html.TagHandler` to your `fromHtml()` request to catch that. Unfortunately, `<div>` is already recognized by the parser, and does not distinguish via `class`, so your `TagHandler` would not get control, and that would require a `fromHtml()` workalike. But I notice that `<span>` is not presently used by `fromHtml()`, so that's a more standards-compliant option without you rolling your own parser.

Comment: interesting, didn't know about that TagHandler thing, cheers!